# Table caption position

Tags: tables, captions

I would like to have my caption at the top right of the table. 
I've already set it at the top right of the paper using:

```
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=off}
```

But I need to have it on the top right of the table, as on picture.
[image: wrong caption position]

The column  width is set with `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.3em}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a minimal working example -- a small, complete document, which we can copy to own computer and test it.

Comment: By the way, the parameter `\tabcolsep` does not govern the width of the columns. Instead, it governs the amount of inter-column whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you load the [threeparttable](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/) package and embed the `\caption` directive and the `tabular` (or `array`) environment inside a `threeparttable` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,threeparttable}
\captionsetup{justification   = raggedleft,
              singlelinecheck = off}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A caption}
\begin{tabular}{|cccccccc|}
\hline
aaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
% optional: provide 'tablenotes' environment if needed
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, Caption is on the same position as it was. Moreover it turned out that the line:
`\captionsetup{justification = raggedleft, singlelinecheck = off}`
shifts image captions to the right as well (They should be centred).

Comment: Sorry, I've pressed enter too early)

Comment: @Yuriy - You have me completely confused. The options `justification = raggedleft` and `singlelinecheck = off` are exactly as in your code, and I used them as well as I thought that this is what you want. If that's not the case after all, please edit your posting to clarify what you want. Alternatively, if you believe that my answer isn't helping me, just let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: I've checked several times, and made table preamble the same as yours:
`\begin{table}[H]
 \centering 
 \begin{threeparttable}
 \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.4em}  
 \caption{} 
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   а & б & в & г & д & е & ж & з & и & й & к & л & м & н & о & п \\ \hline`
but the caption is still there. Apparently the problem is somewhere in another part of my code.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. It finally works. The problem was `\usepackage{floatrow}` that I've tried to use for images. 
Can you please tell how to set `\captionsetup{justification = raggedleft, singlelinecheck = off}`only for the tables.

Comment: @Yuriy - Have you tried setting the option `[table]` when executing `\captionsetup`?